# ubuntu dual boot does not boot windows anymore

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

**Problem:** i can't  boot both Ubuntu and Windows.

**Description:**

1. I just installed  **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit** and **Windows 7 64bit** on my **Lenovo Y500** with UEFI *Legacy Support mode* enabled and did update-grub (GNU GRUB 0.97).
2. on **sda** there is installed **grub** and **Windows MBR**.
3. on **sdb** reside the installations of **Windows 7** and **Ubuntu**
4. i tried boot-repair restore MBR: restores windows boot but i can't boot to grub.
5. i tried boot-repair recommended: can't boot windows 7 from grub menu entry for windows 7. It just shows a black screen without any movement directly afterchoosing the entry. The fan starts to run high. can only boot Ubuntu from grub.

---

**Question:**
How can i make Grub2 boot windows properly?

This setup worked once with Ubuntu 13.04.